# Can you use the Nimble Blade feat for magic attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, feats

Can  you use the `Nimble Blade`[[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=238)] for magic attacks ?

> Benefit: When you attack with a light blade and you have combat advantage, you gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

The feat doesn't specify that it only applies to weapon attacks, so you can benefit from this feat when you use an implement power as long as the implement you use with the power is a light blade.

Comment: Yeah that was my reading, but good to get a second opinion ... thanks